# how to create custom fontstyles and colors UI in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, fonts

I want to create custom fontstyles and colors based on user choice like instagram story editing section.is there any way to create like that? please help me to get through it

i want to customize like this (not exact like this)i want to create my own editor

[image]

Comment: You can provide TextStyle on each and show the selected one.

Comment: then what about color section?

Comment: you can find package on color_picker